# Concept of, Framework for , How to Test View of MVC (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, unit-testing

I am now doing the UI from fresh so I want to make it fully test.
Could anyone suggest the correct way to do this and where should be the good place to start?
such as Concept, Framework.

(I already know some concept of testing)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) can help you with frontend testing.

Answer (score 1):

1. Take a look at [The RSpec Book](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/achbd/the-rspec-book). The book goes over much more than just using RSpec (the testing framework). It also delves into the methodology of BDD (Behavior-Driven Development) starting from testing the UI using a tool like Cucumber all the way down through the rest of the Rails stack. It's probably the best book on the entire subject for practical testing in Rails right now. Most of the concepts in the book will apply to other languages and technologies as well
2. Try the [Cucumber](http://cukes.info/) site. The site has a bunch of documentation and videos to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

[Watir](http://watir.com/) may be useful as a tool and there are various [tutorials](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Tutorial) out there for it.